# Help installing Anritsu Master Software Tools

Tags: software-installation

I'm having issues installing Anritsu Master Software Tools (a free download, although it is not an app it is an installer program). Ive tried it with Wine, but i get an error and it doesn't complete installation.

I need this software to install and be usable, it is required for my job on many levels. If I could be helped with this I would be most grateful.
[image: picture] shows the error message I get when trying to install using Wine

Comment: A search of the WineHQ.com database does not show that app as tested https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=category&iId=49&sAction=view&sTitle=Browse+Applications. Experimentation will be required. Please make screenshots of error messages; click [edit] after you've uploaded the screenshots to an image hosting site like http://imgur.com & add the URLs for the screenshots to yr question.  Also review Wine-related posts here https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/wine & read Wine's own recommendations at https://www.winehq.org/help  Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].